# "Message": "relation \"users\" does not exist", golang

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have an API written in Go, I have the following set of models...

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID       string `sql:"type:varchar(36);primary key"`
    Name     string
    Password string
    Email    string
    Content  []Content
    Location string
    Tracks   []Track
    Avatar   string
    BgImg    string
    Artists  []Artist
}

type Artist struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID string `sql:"type:varchar(36);primary key"`
}

type Content struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID string `sql:"type:varchar(36);primary key"`
}

type Track struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID string `sql:"type:varchar(36);primary key"`
}
```

in my `main.go` file, I'm initialising my database with...

```
drivers.DB().CreateTable(&models.User{})
drivers.DB().CreateTable(&models.Artist{})
drivers.DB().CreateTable(&models.Content{})
drivers.DB().CreateTable(&models.Track{})
```

But I'm getting the error...

```
{
  "_message": {
    "Severity": "ERROR",
    "Code": "42P01",
    "Message": "relation \"users\" does not exist",
    "Detail": "",
    "Hint": "",
    "Position": "15",
    "InternalPosition": "",
    "InternalQuery": "",
    "Where": "",
    "Schema": "",
    "Table": "",
    "Column": "",
    "DataTypeName": "",
    "Constraint": "",
    "File": "parse_relation.c",
    "Line": "1159",
    "Routine": "parserOpenTable"
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you adding the ID field to each struct?  The `gorm.Model` you're embedding already does that.

Comment: Are you trying to override the gorm.Model primary key type of `uint` with `varchar(36)`?

Comment: @JohnWeldon I am, yes. Do I need to remove `gorm.Model`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is because your `Artist`, `Content`, and `Track` structs do not have a parent reference to the `User`, although the `User` has-many references to them.  Also, the embedded type `gorm.Model` already has the ID field.

Try:

```
type Artist struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID string `sql:"type:varchar(36);primary key"`
    UserID string `sql:"type:varchar(36)"`
}

type Content struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID string `sql:"type:varchar(36);primary key"`
    UserID string `sql:"type:varchar(36)"`
}

type Track struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID string `sql:"type:varchar(36);primary key"`
    UserID string `sql:"type:varchar(36)"`
}
```